# Por que o PHP permite "declarar" o $this com extract?

Tags: php, característica-linguagem

Eu estava fazendo uns testes (brincando) com a função `extract` e `compact` do PHP. Estava vendo como essas duas funções se comportavam com a variável `$this`.

Daí realizei os seguintes testes:

Tentei obter o valor:

```
var_dump($this); // Notice: Undefined variable 'this'
```

Tentei atribuir um valor:

```
$this = 1; // Fatal Error:  Cannot re-assign $this
```

Os resultados acima é o óbvio de se esperar. Porém quando eu usei a função `extract` a história mudou.

```
extract(['this' => 1]);

var_dump($this); // int(1)
```

Já dentro de classes isso não acontece.

Gostaria de saber se o comportamento acima com a função `extract`, diferentemente da atribuição direta, é uma comportamento comum ou isso é um bug.

O fato de a linguagem permitir essa "atribuição ao `$this`" usando `extract` pode acarretar algum problema?

Answer (score 0):

O porque dessa permissão é realmente uma coisa que também me intrigou, não é considerado *bug*, pois não afeta o funcionamento da linguagem.

Tentei de todo jeito forçar um *bug* ou comportamento estranho, mas como citou na pergunta, quando usado em classe que é o único lugar em que um `$this` pode ser usado, o código do `extract` não faz efeito.

Usei o método `get_defined_vars()` para verificar se realmente está sendo declarada uma variável com nome `$this` e notei que está declarando essa variável quando o `extract` não está dentro de uma classe não estática, quando está dentro de uma classe não estática ele não faz nada, pois dentro do método `extract` deve haver algum controle para isso, e quando está em uma classe estática o `extract` funciona, porém de nada adianta um `$this` em classe estática.

O máximo que consegui foi tirar uma cópia da classe, ao retornar ela para um ambiente externo (fora da classe) é possível apenas alterar e pegar atributos públicos, nem métodos público podem ser chamados:

**index.php:**

```
require_once "TesteClass.php";
$teste = new TesteClass();
$teste->dump();
$retorno = $teste->ext();

echo "Retorno: ";
var_dump($retorno);
echo "<hr/>";
echo $retorno['this']->atributo."<br/>";
$retorno['this']->atributo = "Teste de troca de atributo fora da classe";

echo "Atributo da classe: " . $teste->getAtributo();
echo "<hr/>";

echo "Tentando acessar metodo public fora da classe (pela copia do this): ";
$retorno['this']->mPublico();
echo "<hr/>";

echo "Tentando acessar metodo privado fora da classe (pela copia do this): ";
$retorno['this']->mPrivado();
echo "<hr/>";
```

**TesteClass.php:**

```
<?php
class TesteClass
{
    public $atributo = "valor do meu atributo";

    public function getAtributo()
    {
        return $this->atributo;
    }

    public function dump()
    {
        echo "Minha classe: ";
        var_dump($this);
        echo "<hr/>";
    }

    public function ext()
    {
        extract(["classe" => get_defined_vars($this)]);     
        echo "Get Defined vars na classe: ";
        var_dump(get_defined_vars());
        echo "<hr/>";
        echo "Atributo do Extract : " . $classe['this']->atributo . "<br/>";
        $classe['this']->atributo = "Novo valor do atributo";
        echo "Novo Atributo do Extract : " . $classe['this']->atributo . "<br/>";
        echo "Novo Atributo do THIS : " . $this->atributo . "<br/>";
        echo "<hr/>";
        echo "Metodo privado chamadao da classe pela variavel do Extract : <br/>";
        $classe['this']->mPrivado();
        echo "<hr/>";
        return $classe;
    }

    private function mPrivado()
    {
        echo "Acessou o metodo privado!";
    }

    public function mPublic()
    {
        echo "Acessou o metodo publico!";
    }
}
```

O teste irá dar um fatal error:

> Fatal error: Cannot access private property TesteClass::$atributo in
>   C:\wamp\www\teste.php on line 11

Como conclusão me parece que é mais um esquecimento dos desenvolvedores que propriamente um bug, ou então viram que não há possibilidade de ocorrer um erro decorrente disso, pois já haviam tratado para que quando chamado por uma classe não estática o método não criasse certas variáveis, e então deixaram isso ocorrer.